# Forcing a Pivot table to refresh in a very complicated scenario

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, pivot

**Detailed description inside**

### Background

I have a spreadsheet with a Pivot table ("PT") that many users will access through my company's web portal.  The users are assumed to have little to no experience with Excel and little to no tolerance for "additional steps".  So user interaction apart from normal pivot operation won't work.

I am running SQL Server 2008 and using a stored procedure to generate the data. I have to use a stored procedure because I need to be able to pass along a parameter from Excel (this is not ideal but I have numerous safeguards).

### Chronological Order of Factors/Solutions

**Complication 1**

A PT cannot directly connect to a stored procedure like it can tables etc.

- **Solution** This means that the data must first be imported into a table (which can connect to a stored procedure) and then this table will be the source for the PT.

**Complication 1A**

When the table refreshes (updates data connection) the PT will not refresh itself because it has no trigger event.

- **Solution**: Use VBA and specifically the worksheet change event on the table's sheet module to force refreshes on PT.  This works great and all was working 100%.

**Complication 2**

When a PT whose is within the same workbook and this workbook is opened from a remote location (web portal), you will get an error that looks like "Error 1004: Source file not found". The PT tries to use the path of the workbook to connect to its source but it sees the temporary URL as its path.

- **Solution**: Instead of directly refreshing the PT using `PivotCache.Refresh`, `RefreshTable` use `Activeworkbook.RefreshAll` which for whatever reason does actually work when the former gave me the `Error 1004`.

**Complication 3**

So now I need to now detect a change in the table and then use `Activeworkbook.RefreshAll`. But despite using `Application.EnableEvents = False` and even setting a boolean to prevent the change event from kicking in when the `Activeworkbook.RefreshAll` is executed, I am getting an infinite loop.

*Worksheet Module:*

```
Private blnAbort As Boolean
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If blnAbort = True Then Exit Sub
        blnAbort = True
        Call Refresh
        blnAbort = False
    End If
End Sub
```

*Standard Module:*

```
Public Sub Refresh()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Possible Solution that caused another problem:**

It seems like the `Activeworkbook.RefreshAll` was being executed and then the macro just continued on while it was still refreshing.  This seemed to be causing the `Enable_Events` event and `blnAbort` to be reset just in time for something to refresh and trigger a change and the whole thing started again.  I changed the data connection property `BackgroundRefresh` to false.

However, now I am getting the error `Method 'RefreshAll' of object '_Workbook' failed` and the debug is just jumping to `Activeworkbook.RefreshAll` which is not helpful.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling the refresh of the source table? If the user refreshes it via a button then you can just force a refresh of the pivot table's pivotcache...

**in the worksheet code-module:**

```
Private Sub BtnRefreshData_Click()
    '// Insert the "refreh" routine or call a procedure to refresh the 
    '// data from the stored procedure here..

    '// Once the data is done being refreshed, manually refresh the pivot cache 
    '// for the pivot table. The code looks like this:

     Sheet1.PivotTables("MyPivotTable").PivotCache.Refresh

    '// If you have a lot of pivot tables to refresh from your "source" data-table
    '// then you can always just do a foreach loop...

     Dim sht1 As Worksheet: Set sht1 = Sheet1
     Dim pTable As PivotTable

     For Each pTable in sht1.PivotTables
         pTable.PivotCache.Refresh
     Next pTable

End Sub
```

Let me know if this helps, or be more specific as to why something straight forward like this won't work and ill do my best to try again. If it does work, let me know! thanks, Brian

**UPDATE:**

So in response to your comments: 
 From what I can tell it sounds like really the only issue you have is the infinite loop created by interwoven events (event that refreshes the pivot table calls the change event, which refreshes the pivot table, etc. etc, etc...). 
 I think the easiest solution for you at this point is to disable all events when the refresh event takes place, which shouldn't fire off the unwanted event (causing the loop). Before the code that refreshes the pivot table put the following code:

```
    '// Start Code Snippet...

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    '// Do your refresh routine here....

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    '// End Code Snippet
```

Does this help? If not I'll try again :) ... thanks, Brian

Comment: There is a listbox that a user selects an option from.  The listbox is linked to a cell.  That cell is a parameter in the data connection and the data connection refreshes whenever this cell value changes. So when the user selects an option from the listbox the data table is updated.  That data table is on "Sheet2".  So in the Sheet2 VBA module, I use the worksheet_change event which will be fired when anything on the sheet changes (the change event goes off whenever the table data updates this way).  In this worksheet_change event PT is signaled to refresh.

Comment: The problem here is that the PivotCache commands will not work.  I had used those originally but I get the error source not found.  When I use the ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll I get no error but I can't get around an infinite loop that is created in the process.

Comment: Oh and thanks for the response! I think this is a perfect storm of the possible issues with Pivot tables and I am not entirely sure this is possible to solve in any conventional methods.

Comment: And Brian I have to keep buttons and user action to an absolute ABSOLUTE minimum.  There is a vast range of experience with these folks and while it may seem simple to us, some of them will already be totally overwhelmed just from Excel prompting them to "Enable Macros" and "Enable Automatic Refresh".  So I am forced to come up with either an elegant (where user is not involved) solution or rework the entire thing (move the spreadsheet off the portal).

Comment: Brian my refresh routine is enclosed within application.enableevents = false / true which did not work at first because my query refreshed in the background and so the VBA would continue even if the data was still refreshing creating an infinite loop because the events would be enabled while it was refreshing.  I turned off the background query part so it wouldn't continue executing code while refreshing and now I get an error "Method 'RefreshAll' of object '_Workbook' failed."

Comment: Hey I going to either re-post a more specific question or just come up with something different.  Thanks for your help though!